# Why am I not getting any Data? Ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, web, frontend, ngrx

I tried to implement Ngrx into my Angular Application, but sadly haven't been able to retrieve any data. Any help is appreciated!

What I'm trying to do in the property.component.ts is to get all the data when the component gets instantiated and just display the data in the `property.component.html`.

`property.component.ts`

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {select, Store} from '@ngrx/store';

import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-property',
  templateUrl: './property.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./property.component.css']
})
export class PropertyComponent implements OnInit {

  properties$ = this._store.pipe(select('properties'));

  constructor(private _store: Store<any>, private _router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._store.dispatch({
      type: '[Property] Get Properties'
    });
    console.log(this.properties$);
  }

  navigateToProperty(id: number) {
    this._router.navigate(['property', id]);
  }

}
```

`property.component.html`

```
<p>test</p>
<p>{{properties$ | async}}</p>
```

`property.service.ts`

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import {PropertyModel} from '../models/property.model';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class PropertyService {
      propertiesUrl = 'someapi';
      private httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
      };

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      getProperties(): Observable<PropertyModel[]> {
        return this.http.get<PropertyModel[]>(this.propertiesUrl, this.httpOptions);
      }
    }
```

`property.actions.ts`

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import {PropertyModel} from '../../models/property.model';


export const GET_PROPERTIES = '[Property] Get Properties';
export const GET_PROPERTIES_SUCCESS = '[Property] Get Properties Success';
export const SEARCH_PROPERTY = '[Property] Get Property';
export const SEARCH_PROPERTY_SUCCESS = '[Property] Get Property Success';

export class GetProperties implements Action {
  public readonly type = GET_PROPERTIES;
  constructor(public retrievedProperties: PropertyModel[]) {}
}

export class GetPropertiesSuccess implements Action {
  public readonly type = GET_PROPERTIES_SUCCESS;
  constructor(public retrievedProperties: PropertyModel[]) {}
}

export class GetProperty implements Action {
  public readonly type = SEARCH_PROPERTY;
  constructor(public searchId: string) {}
}

export type PropertyActions = GetProperties | GetPropertiesSuccess | GetProperty;
```

`property.effects.ts`

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Actions, Effect, ofType} from '@ngrx/effects';

import {GET_PROPERTIES, PropertyActions} from '../actions/property.actions';
import {PropertyService} from '../../services/property.service';
import {mapTo} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()

export class PropertyEffects {

  @Effect()
  getProperties$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<PropertyActions>(GET_PROPERTIES),
    mapTo(this.propertyService.getProperties())
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private propertyService: PropertyService) {}

}
```

and finally my `property.reducers.ts`

```
import {GET_PROPERTIES, GET_PROPERTIES_SUCCESS, PropertyActions} from '../actions/property.actions';
import {PropertyModel} from '../../models/property.model';

export function propertyReducer(properties: PropertyModel[] = [], action: PropertyActions): PropertyModel[] {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PROPERTIES: {
      return [...action.retrievedProperties];
    }
    default: {
      return properties;
    }
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {CustomerComponent} from './customer/customer.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {CustomMaterialModule} from './custom.material.module';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
import {PropertyComponent} from './property/property.component';
import {propertyReducer} from './store/reducers/property.reducers';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    component: CustomerComponent,
    data: {title: 'Customer List'}
  },
  {
    path: 'property',
    component: PropertyComponent,
    data: {title: 'Property List'}
  },
  {
    path: '', // General redirect
    component: CustomerComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomerComponent,
    PropertyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CustomMaterialModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(propertyReducer)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Your effect should dispatch a success and then map the returned data to your state. Right now, you are calling your service but the returned data is not map to your state because the reducer is called before the effect

Comment: How is my reducer being called before my effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5aypp)

Don't forget to dispatch success and error actions and to reduce them.
Also change `mapTo` to `switchMapTo`

```
@Effect()
getProperties$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<PropertyActions>(GET_PROPERTIES),
  switchMapTo(this.propertyService.getProperties().pipe(
    map(props => new GetPropertiesSuccess(props)),
   // catch error here
   // catchError(error => of(new GetPropertiesError(error))),
    ),
  ),

);
```

In your reducer, listen to correct type

```
case GET_PROPERTIES_SUCCESS: {
  return [...action.retrievedProperties];
}
```

For clarity remove `retrievedProperties` from `GetProperties` - the action does not have any retrieved props. The success action should be used to pass them.

In your app module change the reducer setup and don't forget to import the effects:

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
HttpClientModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
// change this
StoreModule.forRoot({properties: propertyReducer}),
// this is needed
EffectsModule.forRoot([PropertyEffects])
],
```

Optional: In your `PropertyComponent` change the the dispatched action to the instance of the `GetProperties` class. That's how it should be used.

```
 this._store.dispatch(new GetProperties());
```

Comment: I tried your code, but localhost seems to be just loading constantly.

Comment: It's hard to debug whole code without actually running it. If you provide a stackblitz example, I'd have a look.

Comment: I added one more thing, the `app.module.ts` if that helps. I'll try and setup a stackblitz in the meantime

Comment: Well donw the rabbit hole i go there are more and more errors in your code. You should go and try an NGRx tutorial. There are many misconceptions here.

Comment: I got that working. I expanded my answer so it has everything. Good luck coding. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5aypp

Comment: How would you do service calls with parameters though? @kvetis

Comment: Use the GET_PROPERTIES with a payload.